# UnsupportedFileFormatException while running test from pom.xml

Tags: maven-2

I am getting this error while running a test from `pom.xml`:

> NoClassDefFoundError: UnsupportedFileFormatException

But the script runs fine when I run the class file directly. What is wrong with it?

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">



<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>FlightBooking</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpiceJet</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>




<dependencies>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.48.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.9.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>



<build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>`enter code here`
                <fork>true</fork>
                <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javac.exe</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <`version`>2.19</version>

          <configuration>
          <includes>
          <include>
          `TestScenario1`.java
          </include>
          </includes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </`plugins`>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
```

I have included following poi jars:

1. `ooxml-schemas-1.1`
2. `poi-3.13-20150929`
3. `poi-examples-3.13-20150929`
4. `poi-excelant-3.13-20150929`
5. `poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929`
6. `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.13-20150929`
7. `poi-scratchpad-3.13-20150929`
8. `xmlbeans-2.6.0`

Comment: In general never use a maven-plugins as dependency. For example `maven-compiler-plugin` ...it simply does not make sense...Why are you defining include rules for maven-surefire-plugin ? Use the default naming conventions...Apart from that a full error message would helpful as well...